# Arraylist and webmethod

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have written a web method in ASP.net which it's output is an ArrayList of cities that is read from Sql server database.
this webmethod is called using Jquery in clientside.
but I don't know how to read each item of array list using jquery. for example every city and it's id equivalent.
Below is my Webmethod:

```
public ArrayList showcity(int s)
    {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            String strConnString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["ConnectionCS"].ConnectionString;
            String strQuery = "select ID, City from tbl_city where stateid=@s";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s", s);
                    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        list.Add(new ListItem(
                       sdr["City"].ToString(),
                       sdr["ID"].ToString()
                        ));
                    }
                    con.Close();
                   return list;
                }
            }
```

and this is my clientside code:

```
function showcity() {
        $.ajax(
    { url: "../AjaxServices/StateCity.asmx/showcity",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: '{s: ' + $('#<%=DpState.ClientID%>').val() + '}',
        success: function(data) {
             ***// what should I write here to access every item separately*** 
          },
        error: function() { alert("Error"); }
    })
}
```

If I use `alert(data.d)` I will get [object][object][object][object],.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself so I share it here, just be careful about `Value` and `Text` they're case sensitive

```
 success: function(data) {
                $.each(data.d, function() {
                    alert(this['Value'] + ':' + this['Text']);
                })
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an actual type and return an array of that type.  So create a City class, mark it serializable, build a `List<City>` in your loop, then return .ToArray().  The return type of your web method should be City[]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ArrayList` being returned, it would be better to return an array with two dimension.